# Is a function between topological spaces continuous if continuous on subspaces?

Tags: general-topology

Assume that there are two topological spaces $X,Y$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$. Furthermore, assume that there exists a collection of sets $\mathcal{B}$ such that

$\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B = X,$

and for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$ the restriction $f|_B$ is continuous with respect to the subspace topology.

Is this enough to say that $f$ is continuous on the whole space?

Comment: Hint: Think of singletons.

Comment: If each $B$ is open, sure! If not, then no, not necessarily. What if, for example, your family of sets were all the singleton sets $\{\{x\} : x \in X\}$, for example?

Comment: Ah great! Thank you. That is a very obvious counterexample I just missed.

Comment: Positive cases: when all $B$ are open, or when the $B$ form a locally finite closed cover. So it's not a strange question to ask...

Comment: Another (obvious) counter-example: Let $X=Y=\Bbb R;$ let $\mathcal B=\{(-\infty,0),[0,\infty)\}$. Let $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$. Let $f(x)=1$ if $x\ge 0.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by others in the comments, this in general fails.
The most relevant positive result (other than those mentioned by @Henno Brandsma) is the [Pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), which states that this holds when $\mathcal B$ is finite and each $B\in\mathcal B$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

A more general statement than @Just a user.

If $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ form a fundamental cover of $X$. Then $f:X\to Y$is continuous if and only if $f|_{U_{\alpha}}$ is continuous $\forall\alpha\in A$

Definition of fundamental cover:-

A cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is called a fundamental cover if $V\subset X$ open $\iff$ $V\cap U_{\alpha}$ is open in the subspace topology $\forall\alpha\in A$ .

It can be proven that an open cover is fundamental. A cover of $X$ by finite number of closed sets is fundamental. A locally finite cover by closed sets is fundamental. In these cases you can conclude continuity. For other cases you have to check by hand as these are only necessary conditions for a cover to be fundamental.